# Could not display Hive tables in IntelliJ IDEA "Database" Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, hive

## Environmnet

- Clusters (VMWare Devices)

  - Apache Hadoop v2.6.5 ( Apache Offical Edition )
  - Apache Hive v1.2.1 ( Apache Offical Edition )
  - MySQL Community Server v5.1.73
- Host (Physical Device)

  - JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3 ( Ultimate Edition )
  - Adopt OpenJDK 1.8.0_265

## Problem

After launching HDFS, YARN, Hadoop History Server, Hive Metastore and HiveServer2, I connected to Hive remotely through IntelliJ IDEA "Database" Plugin. I connected SUCCESSFULLY and excuted my `*.hql` scripts without any exceptions,but there was nothing shown in the "Databases" Plugin, only except the configuration itself. Databases, tables or columns were missing.

There was NOTHING WRONG when I connected to MySQL. Collations, users, schemas, tables, columns and even keys (primary or foreign) were shown in the plugin.

[Contents shown in "Database" Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv2Ff.png)

## Drivers for Apache Hive in IntelliJ IDEA

I used these JAR files as Hive Drivers. All JAR files were copied from my cluster through Xftp6.

- commons-httpclient-3.0.1
- commons-logging-1.1.3
- curator-client-2.6.0
- curator-framework-2.6.0
- hadoop-auth-2.6.5
- hadoop-common-2.6.5
- hive-common-1.2.1
- hive-exec-1.2.1
- hive-jdbc-1.2.1
- hive-metastore-1.2.1
- hive-service-1.2.1
- httpclient-4.4
- httpcore-4.4
- slf4j-api-1.7.5
- zookeeper-3.4.6

## Attached details

### Oct 24th, 2020

I switched Apache Hive Driver to `ver.3.1.2 [stable]` provided by JetBrains, and I got these exceptions when "Test Connection":

```
[ 08S01] Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://master:10000: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://master:10000: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size=1000, use:database=default})
org.apache.hive.org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size=1000, use:database=default}).
```

I also switch to `ver.3.1.1 [stable]` and I got the same exceptions as above.

The 3rd time, I switched to "Custom JARs ..." and added `hadoop-common-2.6.5.jar` and `hive-jdbc-1.2.1-standalone.jar` downloaded from Maven Central Repository. No exceptions thrown when "Test Connection":

```
DBMS: Apache Hive (ver. 1.2.1)
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=mixed
Driver: Hive JDBC (ver. 1.2.1, JDBC3.0)
Ping: 265 ms
```

"OK" and refresh "Database" panel again. I got a popup and these messages shown in "Event log":

[Popups by "Event log"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn0CO.png)

```
2020/10/24
17:23   Connected

17:23   Hive (master)
            enabling autocommit is not supported.
```

Went to "Help -> Tail Log in Console", these were exceptions when I refresh Hive connection:

```
2020-10-24 17:37:18,068 [2272449]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - [+] Start SaveActionManager#beforeAllDocumentsSaving 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,068 [2272449]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - Locating psi files for 0 documents: [] 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,068 [2272449]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - End SaveActionManager#beforeAllDocumentsSaving 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,100 [2272481]   INFO - atabaseCredentialsAuthProvider - Connecting as: root 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,100 [2272481]   INFO - .DatabaseConnectionEstablisher - Connecting to: jdbc:hive2://master:10000 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,104 [2272485]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 10月 24, 2020 9:37:18 上午 org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils parseURL 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,105 [2272486]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 信息: Supplied authorities: master:10000 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,105 [2272486]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 10月 24, 2020 9:37:18 上午 org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils parseURL 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,105 [2272486]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 信息: Resolved authority: master:10000 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,109 [2272490]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 10月 24, 2020 9:37:18 上午 org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection openTransport 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,109 [2272490]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - 信息: Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://master:10000 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,184 [2272565]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Driver: Hive JDBC 1.2.1 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,188 [2272569]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - getDatabaseProductName: Apache Hive 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,188 [2272569]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - release_version: 1.2.1 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,188 [2272569]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Detected: HIVE 1.2.1 
2020-10-24 17:37:18,391 [2272772]   WARN - lij.database.util.ErrorHandler - enabling autocommit is not supported 
enabling autocommit is not supported
The SQL statement:
connect

    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdba.jdbc.BaseExceptionRecognizer.recognizeException(BaseExceptionRecognizer.java:48)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdba.jdbc.JdbcIntermediateFacade.connect(JdbcIntermediateFacade.java:87)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdba.jdbc.UnknownDatabaseIntermediateFacade.connect(UnknownDatabaseIntermediateFacade.java:41)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdba.impl.RemoteFacadeImpl.connect(RemoteFacadeImpl.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:164)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy189.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.database.dialects.base.introspector.AuditFacade.connect(AuditFacade.kt:59)
    at com.intellij.database.layoutedQueries.impl.AdaptIntermediateFacade.connect(AdaptIntermediateFacade.java:26)
    at com.intellij.database.layoutedQueries.BaseFacade.connect(BaseFacade.java:32)
    at com.intellij.database.dialects.base.introspector.DBFacadeProvider.createFacadeWithSingleLeasedConnection(DBFacadeProvider.kt:34)
    at com.intellij.database.dialects.base.introspector.jdbc.JdbcIntrospector.attachToDB(JdbcIntrospector.java:138)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.initIntrospector(DatabaseModelLoader.java:560)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.prepareIntrospection(DatabaseModelLoader.java:547)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.lambda$introspect$1(DatabaseModelLoader.java:314)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.withFacade(DatabaseModelLoader.java:570)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.lambda$introspect$2(DatabaseModelLoader.java:312)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DataSourceSyncManager.lambda$static$0(DataSourceSyncManager.java:51)
    at com.intellij.database.console.session.SessionsUtil$function$1.invoke(SessionsUtil.kt:20)
    at com.intellij.database.console.session.DatabaseSessionManager$Facade.compute(DatabaseSessionManager.kt:338)
    at com.intellij.database.console.session.DatabaseSessionManager$Facade.runSync(DatabaseSessionManager.kt:273)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DataSourceSyncManager.lambda$static$1(DataSourceSyncManager.java:49)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DataSourceSyncManager$SyncProcessor$1.perform(DataSourceSyncManager.java:306)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.introspect(DatabaseModelLoader.java:312)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.lambda$run$0(DatabaseModelLoader.java:200)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.LocalDataSource.performBatch(LocalDataSource.java:1333)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.run(DatabaseModelLoader.java:198)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DataSourceSyncManager$SyncProcessor.performSync(DataSourceSyncManager.java:308)
    at com.intellij.database.util.AsyncTask$Frame$compute$$inlined$supply$1$1.run(AsyncTask.kt:486)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:588)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.database.util.AsyncTask$Frame$compute$$inlined$supply$1.get(AsyncTask.kt:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:629)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:581)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.underProgress(AsyncUtil.java:180)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$asyncFriendlyExecutor$1(AsyncUtil.java:56)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:268)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: enabling autocommit is not supported
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.setAutoCommit(HiveConnection.java:1199)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdba.jdbc.pooling.ConnectionPool.prepareConnectionAfterConnected(ConnectionPool.java:103)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdba.jdbc.pooling.ConnectionPool.obtainOneConnectionIntoPool(ConnectionPool.java:86)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdba.jdbc.pooling.ConnectionPool.connect(ConnectionPool.java:66)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdba.jdbc.JdbcIntermediateFacade.connect(JdbcIntermediateFacade.java:84)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdba.jdbc.UnknownDatabaseIntermediateFacade.connect(UnknownDatabaseIntermediateFacade.java:41)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdba.impl.RemoteFacadeImpl.connect(RemoteFacadeImpl.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
2020-10-24 17:37:49,447 [2303828]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - [+] Start SaveActionManager#beforeAllDocumentsSaving 
2020-10-24 17:37:49,447 [2303828]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - Locating psi files for 0 documents: [] 
2020-10-24 17:37:49,448 [2303829]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - End SaveActionManager#beforeAllDocumentsSaving 
2020-10-24 17:37:49,875 [2304256]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appBigDataIdeGlobalConnectionSettings took 38 ms 
2020-10-24 17:37:52,641 [2307022]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - [+] Start SaveActionManager#beforeAllDocumentsSaving 
2020-10-24 17:37:52,641 [2307022]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - Locating psi files for 0 documents: [] 
2020-10-24 17:37:52,641 [2307022]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - End SaveActionManager#beforeAllDocumentsSaving 
2020-10-24 17:37:55,642 [2310023]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - [+] Start SaveActionManager#beforeAllDocumentsSaving 
2020-10-24 17:37:55,642 [2310023]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - Locating psi files for 0 documents: [] 
2020-10-24 17:37:55,642 [2310023]   INFO - re.component.SaveActionManager - End SaveActionManager#beforeAllDocumentsSaving 
<Nearest above 3 lines repeated many times ...>
```

Here are SQL Logs generated today:

```
-- 2020-10-24 17:17:57 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [session id: 1539943027] connected
-- [ --------------------------------------------------
-- 2020-10-24 17:17:57 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [unknown] [session id: 1539943027] [statement id: 1846946385] 
SELECT 'keep alive'
-- ] --------------------------------------------------
-- 2020-10-24 17:18:00 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [unknown] [session id: 1539943027] [statement id: 1846946385] finished - execution time: 3 s 211 ms
-- 2020-10-24 17:18:00 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [session id: 1539943027] disconnected
-- 2020-10-24 17:21:05 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [session id: 1539943028] connected
-- [ --------------------------------------------------
-- 2020-10-24 17:21:05 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [unknown] [session id: 1539943028] [statement id: 1846946386] 
SELECT 'keep alive'
-- ] --------------------------------------------------
-- 2020-10-24 17:21:05 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [unknown] [session id: 1539943028] [statement id: 1846946386] finished - execution time: 211 ms
-- 2020-10-24 17:21:05 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [session id: 1539943028] disconnected
-- 2020-10-24 17:22:24 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [session id: 1539943029] connected
-- 2020-10-24 17:22:25 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [session id: 1539943029] disconnected
-- 2020-10-24 17:23:50 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [session id: 1539943030] connected
-- 2020-10-24 17:23:51 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [session id: 1539943030] disconnected
-- 2020-10-24 17:33:43 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [session id: 1539943031] connected
-- 2020-10-24 17:33:43 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [session id: 1539943031] disconnected
-- 2020-10-24 17:37:18 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [session id: 1539943032] connected
-- 2020-10-24 17:37:18 [C06_Spark-TV-Massive] [Hive (master)] [session id: 1539943032] disconnected
```

There's still no shemas, tables or columns shown in "Database" panel ...

---

Is there anything I didn't configure or enable so Hive could not display schemas and tables for me? I could only switch IntelliLang service from "Inspections" to "Syntax" level to avoid unexpected "errors" in `*.hql` scripts at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any errors in IDE SQL Log or idea.log? 
Have you tried to use provided jdbc driver?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't make sure where these log files are...

I switched to Jetbrains-provided Apache Hive Driver and get exceptions. Details are modified and attached above.

Comment: Could you try to enable `Introspect using JDBC metadata` option on your data source `Options` tab and check whether it's working or not? 

It looks like jdbc driver compatibility issue, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8116 for details.

Comment: I enaabled this option as you instructed, but it doen't work. There's nothing wrong when I execute `SHOW DATABASES;` in `Database Consoles > Hive (master) > console [Hive (master)]`. No databases or tables are shown in `Database` panel only. MAYBE it's a feature only available for Apache Hive v3.x or even only available for Cloudera Hadoop Distribution (CDH) users?

Comment: To find a proper jdbc driver is the issue. There are a number of compatibility issues:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6050
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15110
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-22563

Could you try to download one from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/ and it's dependencies and try to connect with it?

E.g. in your case is https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/1.2.1/hive-jdbc-1.2.1.pom

Comment: [HIVE-6050](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6050) and [HIVE-22563](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-22563) didn't occur after this question was asked. I think you may misunderstand the question before.

Comment: For some special reason, I can't access to [Maven Central Repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/). So I downloaded [`hive-jdbc-1.2.1-standalone.jar`](https://mirrors.huaweicloud.com/repository/maven/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/1.2.1/hive-jdbc-1.2.1-standalone.jar) and [`hadoop-common-2.6.5.jar`](https://mirrors.huaweicloud.com/repository/maven/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.6.5/hadoop-common-2.6.5.jar) from [Third-party Mirror](https://mirrors.huaweicloud.com/) instead. There's still nothing shown in the Database panel. [A screenshot](https://s1.ax1x.com/2020/11/04/BgFIjU.png)